# How to add screen transitions on mobile views with Zurb Foundation?

Tags: zurb-foundation

How to add screen transitions on mobile views with Zurb Foundation? Are there ways to add fade in screen transition?

Answer (score 0):

I would use animate.css and add a CSS rule to the body tag of

> animation: fadeIn 1s 0.5s;

That will give the new page loaded a fadeIn animation.